# Angular 9 http.get not executing

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-httpclient

I'm unable to get any of my service http calls to execute suddenly. (They were working)
So I've created just a simple sanity check controller method and service method that not only doesn't return anything, but the http get never even executes according to Chrome Dev Tools/network tab.

The Controller method:

```
    sanityCheck(){
        this.accountService.test().subscribe(
            res => {
              console.log("res:",res); //We never get here
            }
          );
    }
```

The Service Call

```
    test():Observable<any> {
        //This line executes, but no network call to postman-echo ever gets made.
        return this.http.get("https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2", httpOptions)
    }

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };
```

I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking, since it worked before.

Comment: Try `return this.http.get("https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2", {responseType: 'json', httpOptions})`

Comment: Still no luck with that

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" Because I can't see any reason outside of weird machine that this would be a thing...

Comment: It's not a CORS issue?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure postman-echo.com is wide open, plus, the http request isn't even being sent - no network activity

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the typescript, I tested it now with data from my api- Except for calling this.httpOptions, and removing const, because "A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword.ts(1248)"

Answer (score 2):

I finally determined that I had added a HttpClientTestingModule to app.module.ts and added it to the imports section.

This module completely short-circuited all http calls, and was difficult to troubleshoot, since it was completely silent - no errors, no responses.

Sorry if this answer is just an impertinent mistake, but this was a very tricky problem with very few answers, and hopefully this can help someone else struggling with a similar issue.